# AngularJS expressions not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm not able to display expression in AngularJS. Below is my the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="appname">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <p>{{appname.product.name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is `javascript.js` file:

```
(function () {
    var appname = angular.module('appname', []);

    var gem = {
        name: "Ring",
        price: 2.9,
        Description: "",
    };

    appname.controller('appCtrl', function () {
        this.product = gem;
    });
});
```

The webpage still displays: `{{appname.product.name}}`.

Comment: Did you ever invoke your function?  I don't see a `()` near the end.

Comment: I did not. Im a beginner in angularjava. im learning through codeschool. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include scope in the controller as well as in view

Change you code like this:

Controller:

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.gem = {
        name:"Ring",
        price:2.9,
        Description:"",
        };
 });
```

HTML:

```
<html data-ng-app="appname">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="appCtrl">
<p>{{gem.name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the codepen link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epgmGd

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a number of things in a wrong way.

Use the **'as'** syntax if you want to follow 'this' (as opposed to $scope) approach.

In your markup:

```
<div data-ng-controller="appCtrl as app">
    <p>{{app.product.name}}</p>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
this.product = {
        name:"Ring",
        price:2.9,
        Description:"",
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this:

First is to use the `$scope` way:

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);

appname.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.gem = {
        name: "Ring",
        price: 2.9,
        Description: "",
    };
});
```

Now modify your view as:

```
<div data-ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <p>{{product.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Another way which you are using is the `this` way:

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);

appname.controller(function() {
    this.gem = {
        name: "Ring",
        price: 2.9,
        Description: "",
    };
});
```

And modify your view as:

```
<div data-ng-controller="appCtrl as main">
    <p>{{main.product.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Also, like @ryanyuyu mentioned in the comment, you need to immediatly invoke your function: like so:

```
(function () {
    // Your code
})();    // Add () at last
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably undocumented case.

In my case, I had got `$window` level variables of the same name that I was declaring on `$scope` level.

After changing the name of the variable it worked.

Strange, as it does recognize `$scope` level variable in js code but when it comes to putting the value in expressions it gets confused.

```
//Global JS variable
var currentLocationName = "Nice Location";
```

I was copying this global variable at `$scope` level.

```
$scope.currentLocationName = $window.currentLocationName;
```

And was having it in the expression in my `HTML` view.

```
<b>Your current location is {{ currentLocationName }}</b>
```

And this was not working. I changed the name at `$scope` level and it worked.

My two cents!